# PHP CS Fixer: spawn php-cs-fixer ENOENT. executablePath not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, php-cs-fixer

**My configuration / steps to reproduce the error:**

1. Installed Visual Studio Code Version 1.22.1
2. Installed PHP CS Fixer Globally by:
   `composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer`
3. Added Environment Variable: `C:\Users\khalil\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\php-cs-fixer`
4. Verified running following command (php-cs-fixer).
   `Output: Version: PHP CS Fixer 2.11.1 Grey Devil by Fabien Potencier and Dariusz Ruminski`
5. Installed Extension for vs-code: php cs fixer

Still getting the error:
`PHP CS Fixer: spawn php-cs-fixer ENOENT. executablePath not found`

Note: *I am on Windows 10 64bit*

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked out for me on Windows 10, modify if you have different folder structure.

```
"phpcbf.executablePath": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\phpcbf.bat",
"phpcbf.executablePathWindows": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\phpcbf.bat"
```

I am using `phpcbf` extension but yours is probably something like

```
"php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\php-cs-fixer.phar",
"php-cs-fixer.executablePathWindows": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\php-cs-fixer.bat",
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Windows 10 & VS Code, You can use:**

1. Install Composer global & see: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#installation
2. Add **C:\Users{My Username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin** to **PATH** in **System environment**
3. Use config:

   "php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "php-cs-fixer",

   "php-cs-fixer.executablePathWindows": "php-cs-fixer.bat",